# Capistrano -- the task `staging:symlink' does not exist

Tags: deployment, capistrano, symlink, staging

I'm attempting to deploy to a server via Capistrano and I keep getting the error the task `staging:symlink' does not exist.

I've run cap:deploy setup and cap deploy successfully getting the releases and shared directories created but the above error always shows at the end and I think it's stopping my code from getting moved to the root of the directory where it belongs.

I'm new at using Capistrano and I've Googled the issue but I cannot find anything that helps. I can include my code and everything I just don't know what to show to help... let me know!

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

The built-in symlink task for capistrano 2.x is `cap deploy:symlink`.

`staging:symlink` is not a valid task, unless you've defined it yourself. If you're not defining this, you are accidentally calling it somewhere in your config files (`deploy.rb` or one of your staging config files, if you're using multistage).

Additionally, `deploy:symlink` should be called automatically as part of the `deploy` task. You don't need to call it manually.